# frequently adding overlay to mkmapview

Tags: iphone, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am developing a running app, where i have to show the total distance covered in the form of route (Start point to current point), I want to know that location manager will frequently send me the location coordinates, and then i have to add those into an array and to pass that to overlay view to draw the route. But as user is running and coordinates are storing into array simultaneously, how should i increase the route overlay for the newly added coordinate? should i call  [self.mapView addOverlay:jogPoint]; after certain time interval every time or is there any efficient way?

Comment: Check out Apple's Breadcrumb sample for how to make a dynamic overlay.

Comment: @LewisGordon it is not showing any overlay when i move from one location to certain distance, it is just dropping the pin to my current location only.

Comment: It has a minimum delta of 10m.  I have no problem getting it to draw a path showing my route.

Comment: @LewisGordon can you please give me some idea that how it is working? so that i can try it by myself. As i need to update the overlay frequently, this is my main issue